# как переписываться с пользователем от лица бота и обратно получать сообщения? Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

пользователь должен отправить сообщение после нажатия на инлайн кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытался использовать машину состояний, но когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку то сохраненные стираются

```
# отправка, получение сообщений и вывод ссылки
```

async def sendmsg(message: Message, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
recipient_message = f"**‼️ Новое сообщение от ?:**\n\n*{message.text}*"  # текст получателю
data = await state.get_data()  # получение всех сохраненных данных состояний
await bot.send_message(data['recipient_id'], recipient_message, reply_markup=send_back())  # отправка
await message.answer(f"""Отправлено ✅